# JavaScript confirmation window always returning false on Safari for iPhone

Tags: javascript, iphone, knockout.js, mobile-safari

I'm using Knockout.JS to power a form and I have a button that when pressed displays a confirmation window. Only on Safari for iPhone it always returns false. It works with Chrome on my iPhone, and on my iPad and laptop it works on all browsers(including Safari). There are no errors either.

```
self.submitPayment = function(){
    var errors2 = ko.validation.group(secondValidationGroup);
    if (errors2().length == 0) {
        if(confirm_reservation() == true){
            finalizePayment(); //calls function which displays a new div
        }
        else{
            alert('False was returned'); //displays before I even make a selection
        }
    }
    else{
        errors2.showAllMessages();
    }
}

 //used to confirm submission for submitPayment 
function confirm_reservation(){
    var conf = confirm('Click OK to submit your payment');
    return conf;
}
```

Before I even make a selection, I get the 'False was returned' alert. So basically it's not even letting me make a selection before it returns the value.

**edit - It is now working and I think I may have encountered a bug**

I cleared my cookies/cache on my phone and restarted it and then it proceeded to work properly.

Comment: @mplungjan how will that solve anything? I stated above that it only does this on iPhone Safari browser. It works fine on all desktop browsers that I've tried it with.

Comment: Solve nothing but impossible to test unless you have something that can be loaded

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem due the asycnhronus things, your  "confirm_reservation" method doesnot wait the confirm result, and return false directly.. Can you try below confirm block changing with yours.

```
confirm('Click OK to submit your payment', function(result) {
  if(result) {
    finalizePayment();
  } else {
    alert('False was returned'); //displays before I even make a selection
  }    
});
```

Comment: Nothing is returned when I try this, not even when I press cancel. See my edit above. Maybe I implemented it incorrectly.

Comment: it can be ios safari bug, please google it.. If it is a bug you should  give up using javascript confirm. You can do it with your way like opening a dialog and then pressing ok you contine your flow..

Comment: On what browsers do confirm have a callback method? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.confirm

Comment: @AOZ I think you are right that it was a bug. I cleared my cookies/cache, restarted my phone and now it's working.

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
if(confirm('Your question')) 
{ 
 // do things if OK
}
else
{
// do things if KO
}
```

Comment: This doesn't wait for a response. It returns false immediately, just like my original implementation. Very strange, I have no idea why it's doing that.

Answer (score 0):

After AOZ suggested that it may have been a bug, I cleared my cookies/cache and restarted my phone and then it proceeded to work. I am using my original method and it now works properly.

Comment: But what if your user's run into this issue? You can't expect them to restart their phone to get your app to work. I am experiencing this as well on iPhone 5 iOS 7.0.4. I just noticed it today though, really unpredictable bug.