# Javascript confirm dialog always returns false on iPhone 6S and iPhone 6S Plus

Tags: javascript, iphone, mobile-safari

We have two phones, as well as the some phones on browserstack.com (all iPhone 6S and 6S plus).  These phones always return false from a javascript confirm dialog, regardless of what the user presses.  This only occurs within Safari and only on iPhone 6S and 6S plus.  If you use chrome on the same phone, the javascript confirm dialog works as expected.

We created a JSfiddle:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/McQm5/5/

I found the following question, which suggest clearing the browser cache/cookies and restarting the phone, but this did not fix the problem.  And on BrowserStack, you're not able to do this.

[JavaScript confirmation window always returning false on Safari for iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20871356/javascript-confirmation-window-always-returning-false-on-safari-for-iphone)

This is definitely an Apple Safari bug.  Any idea what we can do about it?

Comment: If it's a Safari bug, not sure you can do anything about it, apart from not using confirm, maybe use a boostrap dialog instead,.. Look nicer anyway.

Comment: @Keith Do you know which versions are affected?  Is there an Apple ticket for this that you know of?

Comment: Waited until I got home, as my wife has the 6S plus, and the fiddle you sent works fine on here phone.  Click OK and it says working fine, click cancel and it says Not working...

Comment: That's interesting.  The problem occurs on BrowserStack.com 's phones, so it's not just something goofy with our setup.

Comment: I wonder if these phone come with some extensions installed as default, eg. security extension / add blocker etc.  And one of these is causing the problem.